# Why do some "OAuth" providers ask for personal info?

Tags: authentication, oauth, authorization, openid-connect

I don't mean to start another OAuth vs OpenID discussion, but I want to share the underlying cause of my confusion.

When I want a Client to process my google docs for something, I have to go through my google account. But if its only use is to process docs, why is it asking for my email address on the consent page? Does this make it an OpenID flow?

To be honest, in my experience, almost every client asks for my email.

Which begs the question: If personal information like email is all that's needed for authentication, what makes OpenID spec that much more compliant?